# XSLT code does not copy the existing attributes of the Target Element

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

1.) Target XML is:

```
<Node1>
    <Node2>
        <Node3 attx="1" attry="2" attrz="3">
            <child1 att1="1" attr2="2" attr3="3"/>
            <child1 att1="1" attr2="2" attr3="3"/>
            <child1 att1="1" attr2="2" attr3="3"/>       
            </Node3>   
      </Node2>
</Node1>
```

2.) XSLT code:

```
<xsl:template match="Node1/Node2/Node3">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <BasicDouble attr1="104" attr2="12312" attr3="0" />
    <BasicEnum attr1="104" attr2="12312" attr3="0" />
      <Pair Key="0" Value="First"/>
      <Pair Key="1" Value="Last"/>
    </BasicEnum>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

3.) Obtain Result

```
<Node1>
    <Node2>
        <Node3>
            <child1 att1="1" attr2="2" attr3="3"/>
            <child1 att1="1" attr2="2" attr3="3"/>
            <child1 att1="1" attr2="2" attr3="3"/>   
            <BasicDouble attr1="104" attr2="12312" attr3="0" />
            <BasicEnum attr1="104" attr2="12312" attr3="0" />
                <Pair Key="0" Value="First"/>
                <Pair Key="1" Value="Last"/>            
        </Node3>   
    </Node2>
</Node1>
```

The problem is that with this code the attributes of Node3 are deleted. 
How should I alter the script so that the attributes of the Node3 are copied ? 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add an `<xsl:copy-of select="@*" />` as first child of the `<xsl:copy>` element to copy all attributes of `Node3`.
I also removed a closing `/` at one element to make the XSLT well-formed.

```
<xsl:template match="Node1/Node2/Node3">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />                      <!-- copy attributes -->
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <BasicDouble attr1="104" attr2="12312" attr3="0" />
    <BasicEnum attr1="104" attr2="12312" attr3="0">  <!-- no closed element -->
      <Pair Key="0" Value="First"/>
      <Pair Key="1" Value="Last"/>
    </BasicEnum>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for!